# Adding total count labels to geom_bar(stat = "identity") in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I'm trying to add the total count to a `geom_bar` graph where I have the command (`stat = "identity"`) in `ggplot2`. I'm having issues with the stat = "count" function and the `label = after_stat(count)` function. I_m running R version 4.3.1 through R Studio.

The base code without any count:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(gold, aes(x=Site, y=APIDAE, fill=Site, colours))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Sites", values = gold_cols)+
  ylab(label = "Famille apidae")+
  ylim(0, 50)+
  ggtitle("Présence Apidae entre sites")
```

Gives me this:

[image]

I've tried adding the `after_stat(count)` function and here is the error message I get:

> Error in `geom_text()`:
> ! Problem while computing stat.
> ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
> Caused by error in `setup_params()`:
> ! `stat_bin()` must only have an x or y aesthetic.
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I've also tried this:

```
ggplot(gold, aes(x=Site, y=APIDAE, fill=Site, colours))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Sites", values = gold_cols)+
  ylab(label = "Famille apidae")+
  ylim(0, 50)+
  geom_text(
    aes(label = APIDAE),
    colour = "white", size = 3,
    vjust = 1.5, position = position_dodge(.9)
  )+
  ggtitle("Présence Apidae entre sites")
```

[image]

I don't want 4 values within each bin, I want the sum within the bin.

I tried `stat = "count"` without much luck:

```
ggplot(gold, aes(x=Site, y=APIDAE, fill=Site, colours))+
geom_bar(position = "dodge")+
  geom_text(
    stat = "count",
    aes(
      label = after_stat(count)
      ),
    position = position_dodge(),
    color = "black",
    size = 8,
    vjust = -0.2
  )+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Sites", values = gold_cols)+
  ylab(label = "Famille apidae")+
  ylim(0, 50)+
  ggtitle("Présence Apidae entre sites")
```

Gives me this error:

> Error in `geom_bar()`:
> ! Problem while computing stat.
> ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
> Caused by error in `setup_params()`:
> ! `stat_count()` must only have an x or y aesthetic.
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I'm about to give up and just add the numbers manually in Powerpoint.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try with `stat_summary(aes(label = after_stat(y)), fun = "sum", geom = "text")` to compute the sum your `y` variable and add it as a label . For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`.

Comment: Thank you! It is not elegant but it certainly does what I was trying to do. Much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in my comment, if you want to compute the sum of a variable use `stat_summary`. `stat="count"` will compute the count aka the number of observations and maps the result on `y`, i.e. it does not work when a variable is mapped on `y` and will result in an error.

Using some fake example data based on the `ggplot2::mpg` dataset:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Make example data
gold <- mpg |>
  dplyr::count(class, trans) |>
  dplyr::rename(Site = class, APIDAE = n)

ggplot(gold, aes(x = Site, y = APIDAE, fill = Site)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  stat_summary(
    aes(label = after_stat(y)),
    fun = "sum", geom = "text", vjust = 0,
    position = position_nudge(y = 1)
  ) +
  # scale_fill_manual(name = "Sites", values = gold_cols) +
  # ylim(0, 50) +
  ylab(label = "Famille apidae") +
  ggtitle("Présence Apidae entre sites")
```

[image]

However, perhaps the easiest approach would be to properly aggregate your dataset before passing it to ggplot2. This way you can add the labels without the need of `stat_summary()`:

```r
gold <- gold |>
  dplyr::summarise(APIDAE = sum(APIDAE), .by = Site)

ggplot(gold, aes(x = Site, y = APIDAE, fill = Site)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = APIDAE),
    vjust = 0,
    position = position_nudge(y = 1)
  ) +
  # scale_fill_manual(name = "Sites", values = gold_cols) +
  # ylim(0, 50) +
  ylab(label = "Famille apidae") +
  ggtitle("Présence Apidae entre sites")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, it is very much appreciated.